# How to change graph dynamically on click of button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Hello, dear friends Changing the graph based on button please share your reference?**

here My code is Code

```
<div class="btn-group">
            <button onclick="myFunction1()"> Hoursly </button>
            <button onclick="myFunction2()"> Days </button>
            <button onclick="myFunction3()"> Weakly </button>         
            <button onclick="myFunction4()"> Months </button>
        </div>

    <script src="public/chartjs/Chart.js"></script>

    <div class="container" id="getText" style="display: none;">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
```

How to change the graph on click of button as i'm not sure about these things

```
 <script>    
  function myFunction() {
    var div = document.createElement('canvas');
    div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('myChart').innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
    </script>
```

please share your references.

Comment: you could add a parameter to you function: `function myFunction(typology) { ..... }` and call it like this: `myFunction('Hoursly')`, `myFunction('Days')`, `myFunction('Weakly')`, `myFunction('Months')`

Comment: here my doubt is canvas id based the javascript was loading how to get changing,<canvas id="myChart"></canvas> get from javascript loaded how to button click?

Comment: pass it as a parameter, like: `var ctx = document.getElementById(typology).getContext("2d");` where `typology` is the var passed to the function